# Cassandra: decommissioning a seed node

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Cassandra conceptual questions: I have a 5-node cluster up and running. Now that all nodes are bootstrapped, does the list of seed nodes that each node knows about matter? If I'm planning on decommissioning a seed node, do I need to update other nodes' configurations and remove the to-be-decommissioned node's IP from the seed node list or does it not matter since all nodes are fully joined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you decommission a seed node in a bootstrapped and working ring the cluster will keep working since every node is already up. However the correct procedure before decommissioning a seed node is to choose an existing node as new seed by adding its ip address to other nodes' cassandra.yaml; removing from all cassandra.yaml the old seed address. 
HTH,
Carlo

Comment: Thanks @Carlo Bertuccini! I removed the old seed nodes from the cluster yesterday with no adverse effects. Will update everyone's cassandra.yamls with a new seed node.